# In C language,How to print all binary numbers of size N without 2 consecutive 0's with recursion

Tags: c

How to print all binary numbers of size N without 2 consecutive 0's with recursion?
without using arrays at all,nor loops.
and they need to be printed by order like.
for example:
N=3:
010
011
101
110
111

Comment: Yup, can be done with two recursive functions: one function to compute the next number, and as the base case, another function to display that number in binary. My solution only works for N < 32, since the functions pass the number down the recursion chain as a 32-bit value.

Comment: I only need this for N<=16

Comment: By coding it yourself, SO is not a coding service. Show your try.

Comment: I'm not asking for a given code..I'm asking for a direction to start with.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different questions here. First is algorithmic: how to perform the task recursively independently of any language or constraint. Simple:

- the recursive function takes a sequence of 0 or 1
- if the length of the sequence is N, just print it and return
- else if last element is a 1 recurse two times, once by adding a 0 to the sequence, once by adding a 1
- else recurse only once by adding a 1

Just call that function with a singleton 0 and a singleton 1 and you are done.

The second part is the C implementation. You can use an int (provided N is not greater than the number of bits in an int) and use bit shifting, keeping the number of bits set to store a sequence. The actual implementation if left as an exercise...

Comment: Without using an array I'm not sure how you can get a sequence and count the length of it..

Comment: @Eran: use two different variables: one for the sequence of bits and one for the length.

Comment: Still dont get to see how it works..
Every thing I try I'm losing the first "0" I had..